# Installing mongodb on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

So, I'm trying to install mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04, I followed the steps described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) but the service fail to start. When I run `sudo systemctl status mongodb` I end up with this :

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since dim. 2016-07-24 11:33:25 WEST; 17s ago
   Process: 21404 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, statu
  Main PID: 21404 (code=exited, status=14)

juil. 24 11:33:25 younes-X551CA systemd[1]: Started High-performance,schema-free document-orien
juil. 24 11:33:25 younes-X551CA systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, s
juil. 24 11:33:25 younes-X551CA systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
juil. 24 11:33:25 younes-X551CA systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still don't know/don't understand what caused all this but a system reboot got rid of it...